# How can I automate the IDs of my HTML headings?

Tags: css, headers

```
<h3 id="My_Heading">My Heading</h3>
<h3 id="My_Awesome_Heading">My Awesome Heading</h3>
```

Whatever your heading text is, is what the id of the header is

Is this something that can be automated?  I saw this on a websites code with firebug.  If it is automatic, what is it called?

Comment: But your heading text and ID are not the same in those cases; one is "My_Heading"; the other is "My Heading".

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a little bit of jQuery

To take the ID and create your H3 text from that...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h3').each(function() {
        var newHeading = $(this).attr('id'); //Get the ID
        newHeading = newHeading.replace('_', ' '); //Replace the _ with a space
        $(this).text(newHeading); //Replace the H3 text with the new heading
    });
});
```

...or to take the heading text and generate the ID from that...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h3').each(function() {
        var newID = $(this).text(); //Get the H3 text
        newID = newID.replace(' ', '_'); //Replace spaces with _
        $(this).attr('id', newID); //Attach the new ID
    });
});
```

Of course, these both rely on the user having JS and for that reason, you should make sure you have a suitable fall-back for users with JS off

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done without some external script.

If you already use e.g. PHP/ASP to display the pages I would use that.

However you have to be cautions when you are going to automate this.

Remember `id`s MUST be unique on the page.

Also keep in mind that you should 'normalize' the generated `ids` to follow the rules for [ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids).

What do you want this for. Do the ids enable users to make use of ['internal' links](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23154/how-can-i-automate-the-ids-of-my-html-headings#answer-23160) on the page?